# simplifying variable.handler = function {}

Tags: function, client-side, javascript

I'm brushing up on my JS, and I don't know how to ask this, exactly.

I have this:

```
text_area.onkeyup = function() {
  var text_length    = this.value.length;
  var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

  feed_back.innerHTML = "<strong>" + text_remaining + "</strong> charactres remaining";
}
```

It works. However, should I be able to take the function and pull it out to something like this?

```
function countDown() {
  var text_length    = this.value.length;
  var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

  feed_back.innerHTML = "<strong>" + text_remaining + "</strong> charactres remaining";
}
```

and just call the function by its name?

```
text_area.onkeyup = countDown();
```

This has **never** worked for me, across multiple projects.

Should it? Why doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're executing the function during the assignment, so the return value from the function becomes attached to the event. Instead you should attach a reference:

```
text_area.onkeyup = countDown
```

Or if countdown has parameters you want to pass with it then you can use a `function` to make sure they don't get lost. Something like this:

```
text_area.onkeyup = function(){ countDown(paremeter1, paremeter2); }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the function() {...} part. That's really useful.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to use:

```
text_area.onkeyup = countDown;
```

Without the parenthesis.

`countDown` is a reference to the actual function object `countDown`.  It's simply a reference, and the function won't be called or executed.

`countDown()` actually *calls* the function, and evaluates to whatever it returns.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because `()` actually calls the function -- effectively setting `text_area.onkeyup` to the return value of `countDown` rather than the function itself.

Try this instead:

```
text_area.onkeyup = countDown;
```

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't because you're assigning the result of a function call instead of a function reference. Should be:

```
text_area.onkeyup = countDown;
```